# Right justification of wedge of symbols in C

Tags: c, formatting

I'm using this function:

```
void wedge(char what, int lines) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%c", what);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And trying to get these output variations:

```
               #           #   #####   #####
               ##         ##   ####     ####
               ###       ###   ###       ###
               ####     ####   ##         ##
               #####   #####   #           #
```

I was able to get the first and the third kind of wedges, by simply playing around with ascending and descending those 'i' and 'j'. But I cannot make the second and the fourth options. I think they're right justified, but I don't know how to make them like that. Should be something simple with the same function, as this is for my beginners C course.

Comment: Tip: Get used to counting from zero. For example, if you want to do something five times, use `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)` instead of `for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)`. Do this because many loops need to start at zero (e.g. indexes of an array), and it's important to be consistent in how you do things (because it's less error-prone and easier to read).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't do it myself, I took this function example right from my course. But that's nice advice!

Answer (score 0):

On line `i`, you want to:

1. Output `i` hashes
2. Output `lines-i` spaces
3. Output 3 spaces
4. Output `lines-i` spaces
5. Output `i` hashes
6. Output 3 spaces
7. Output `lines-i+1` hash
8. Output `i-1` spaces
9. Output 3 spaces
10. Output `i-1` spaces
11. Output `lines-i+1` hashes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still can't understand how the function should look like to achieve that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm confused. You already showed how to print a character a number of times based on a variable.

Comment: Actually, the function was given in my course as example for the first wedge. I had to find out how it's working and produce the other wedges. I was able to do the 1st & 3rd by simply playing around with i & j. But no matter what I did, the other 2 weren't printing out. Actually, I don't understand why the function works the way it does...

Answer (score 0):

In the console, you can make indent with " "(space) or "\t"(tab).

In most cases, " "(space) is more consistent.

So the 2nd pattern may generate in this way:

```
void wedge2(char what, int lines) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= lines; j++) {
            if(j<=lines-i)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("%c", what);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and 4th pattern may generate this way:

```
void wedge4(char what, int lines) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= lines; j++) {
            if(j<i)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("%c", what);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's working, thank you very much! The patterns are reversed though - your wedge4 comes as the 2nd with me. Unfortunately, I don't really understand why this function works the way it does, even for the 1st wedge in my example...

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the pattern order. In typical terminal, every character occupies the same width. So, you can printf(" ") to indent a character space. To see it more obviously, you can change " " into "_", to see what's printed. And perhaps even printf("%c",j) may also be helpful for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Maybe you can help me to understand this better. In the first example that I wrote on the post, it makes the 1st wedge. But if I set 'i = lines, i >=1, i--' and 'j=lines, j>=i, j--' it still gives me the 1st wedge. If I set 'i++' and 'j--' then it gives me the 3rd wedge. I tried printf("%c", j) and it just prints another symbol next to each "#". I don't understand, why when I set both 'i' and 'j' to decline from lines to 1, it still gives me the 1st wedge...

Comment: Please make sure you've added **printf(" ");** (print a single space) to indent the beginning of the "#" characters.

Comment: Thank you. I want to learn Python, but my course include some C. I guess if I really want to understand this example, I'll need to make a separate post here, asking exactly what I don't understand. Maybe I'll do that...